# Editing tag after creating a proposed change

Tags: support, documentation

I found a "request topic" for Neo4j in the Python section.
I had some examples in a project I did before, so I added a few examples into that section as the py2neo interface to neo4j is not trivial to figure out.

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/92713?draftId=78253#commentId=17116

Some chap comes along and says

> This is not the place for library docs. Instead, create a tag.

I can't find the place to edit tags. Anything obvious I'm missing out? Because what I definitely don't want to do is write the whole thing again.

I don't get it though.. it's an example in Python, so does it not belong in the Python tag?

Answer (score 4):

> it's an example in Python, so does it not belong in the Python tag?

No. You are attempting to document a *library*, which is completely different from a language. Only language features should be documented under the language tag itself. Library documentation belongs under the tag associated with the library.

This is the only sensible arrangement. To attempt to document all libraries with bindings to a particular language under that language's documentation would lead to madness. Not least because topics are now restricted to a limited number of examples.

> can't find the place to edit tags

No one said anything about editing tags. The suggestion was to add your documentation to the documentation for the library's tag. That would be either [neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neo4j) or [py2neo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/py2neo).

Documentation [has already been created for the Neo4j tag](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/neo4j/topics). You will need to propose Documentation for the py2neo tag, if you think it is warranted. You can propose documentation for a new tag using the big blue button on the [main Documentation page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation).